# Should the user hover-boxes feature appear in the privileges list?

Tags: feature-request

I think that the threshold of user hover-boxes should appear in the privileges page as it is a privilege.

Answer (score 11):

I agree. If [reduced advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) is there, the user card should also be.

It is where people will look for it, and adding it will prevent a lot of questions or confusion.

Further research reveals it is already on the [Established User](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) page, which a somewhat good place as long as it is displayed at 1000 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so. This is not a privilege, it is a customisation bonus. Privileges relates to actions that impacts the community (open/close up/down votes, protect question, moderator tools, flag, ...). Profile does not.

Reduced advertising defies this statement. But this is a huge improvement in the user experience on the stacks sites. I think user cards does not deserves such a highlight.

Comment: [Reduced advertising](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads), which is my way of saying you're rationalizing. It does make sense to add the user card to that list - it is where people will look for it, and it will prevent a lot of questions.

Comment: @Kobi to be noted that reduce ads is not a privilege in sites outside the trilogy (Did not check all, but [security.se], [gaming.se] does not have it). But it's indeed an exception to my remark. :(

Comment: That's a good counterpoint! excellent argument we're having here. Maybe it belongs in the [Established User](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) page? It does mean hiding it a little...

Comment: It's in the established user page!

Comment: So it is! I never read anything. Maybe I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Kobi seems the privileges pages are wiki pages :P (I can see it on meta, but not on gaming... need more rep I guess)

Comment: @M'vy - What do you mean? You can edit privileges pages on some sites, but can't see them on other sites? remarkable!

Comment: @Kobi I mean I have an edit/history link for privileges pages like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user (on meta), but not on gaming.

Comment: @M'vy - Ohhh... That's sort of nice.